# Segmentation fault Core dumped on virtual machine

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, virtual-machine

In a function, I created the following char array.

```
char key1[500]="";
```

I am looping through index "i" in the function and copying values of inputFileArray which is a global variable through an index initialIndex (a global index).

```
key1[i++]= inputFileArray[initialIndex++];
```

This statement is resulting in error Segmentation Fault(core dumped) when I run.

BTW, this worked fine on another machine in which I compiled using visual studio c++ editor. I get this error when I try to run this on a ubuntu 13.10 on virtual machine. Appreciate your answers.

Comment: And the value of `i` stays below `500`?

Comment: You appear to have omitted essentially all of the relevant code, which essentially makes this impossible to answer.

Comment: Just because the code does not segfault on another machine does not mean that your indexes are correct. You could have memory allocated for your program outside of the array so even though you index out over the edge, so to speak, you will not segfault. Then on another machine as soon as you go out of bounds you'll be outside of the memory allocated to your program by the operating system and you'll segfault your pants of. I.E. provide more code.

Comment: You might also want to read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

> This statement is resulting in error Segmentation Fault(core dumped) when I run.

Learn to use a debugger (usually GDB on Linux). You may want to start [here](http://shop.fsf.org/product/debugging-gdb-gnu-source-level-debugger-10/).

Run your program under debugger, and verify that `i < 500` and that
 `initialIndex < sizeof(inputFileArray)`.

> this worked fine on another machine

Yes, bugs are often like that: code that works fine (*appears* to work fine) on one machine crashes on the next.